# Is it true that $[\pi^n] $ is a prime number for only finitely many integers $n$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, pi, primality-test

let  $[\pi^n] $ be the integer part of $(\pi^n)$, I did mathematica code up to $10^4$   to test primality of $[\pi^n] $ , I have got it could be  prime for $n=1,3,4,12$ , Now are there other ? and Is true that  $[\pi^n] $ is a prime number  for only finitely many integers $n$? ?

Mathematica code

```
PrimeQ[Table[IntegerPart [Pi^n],{n ,10^4}]]
```

Comment: I think you mean to ask whether $[\pi^n]$ is prime for only finitely many integers $n$

Comment: yes this what i meant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the prime number theorem, the density of primes around $k$ is approximately $1$ in $\log k$.  We often approximate this to say $k$ has one chance in $\log k$ of being prime.  The expected number of primes is then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{\log(\lfloor \pi^n \rfloor)}\approx \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n \log \pi}$$
which diverges logarithmically, so we would expect infinitely many primes of this form.

Comment: Now I think the next question what is the form of n for the titled number being a prime number ?

Comment: This doesn't help in finding a specific one.  You would expect five by the time $n$ is $e^{5\log \pi-0.577} \approx 172$, so you have been unlucky.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A059792), you overlooked several, starting with

$$\lfloor\pi^{73}\rfloor= 1958577254745770740635072198655932631$$

See also [A077547](https://oeis.org/A077547) and [A001672](https://oeis.org/A001672).

Note, the OEIS sequence has $10$ primes for $n\le10^4$, which agrees reasonably well with what Ross Millikan's answer would give for an expected number, namely $\sum_{n=1}^{10^4}{1\over n\log\pi}\approx{4\log10\over\log\pi}\approx8$.

Comment: This what I want exactly

Comment: You might want to explore what went wrong in your Mathematica program.